# How to get the multiple data inside the json curly braces? Swift

Tags: json, swift

How to get the multiple data inside the json curly braces in swift3?

Can i use this code to get multiple data? (get "crew_id","crew_name","crew_email")

```
if let crew = user!["crew"] as? [String:Any], let crewName = crew["crew_name"] as? String {
print(crewName)
```

JSON

```
crew ={
    "crew_avatar" = "http://ec2-52-221-231-3.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/gv/images/profile_image/Pang_Kang_Ming_916210_0e9.jpg";
    "crew_contact" = 0123456789;
    "crew_email" = "pang@xover.com.my";
    "crew_gender" = Male;
    "crew_id" = PP000001;
    "crew_name" = "Pang Kang Ming";
    "crew_preferred_name" = PKM;
    "crew_qrcode" = "images/qrcode/qrcode_085960293a5378a64bec6ebfa3c89bb7.png";
};
message = "Login Sucessfully";
result = success;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, just add the values you want to unwrap as below, just be aware that if one of the optional binding does not unwrap, even if others unwrap if statement will not be executed, consider separating the if statements.

Depends on all being returned in the json.

```
if let crew = user!["crew"] as? [String:Any],
let crewName = crew["crew_name"] as? String,
let crewId = crew["crew_id"] as? String {
 print(crewName)
 print(crewId)
}
```

Recommended way, even if some values are not present in the json response, you will be able to get the other values.

```
   if let crew = user!["crew"] as? [String:Any] {
    if let crewName = crew["crew_name"] as? String {
      print(crewName)
    }
    if let crewId = crew["crew_id"] as? String {
      print(crewId)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "yourJsonFileName", withExtension: "json") {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])

                let jsonData = json as! [[String:Any]]
                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    let projectName = jsonData.flatMap { $0["crew_avatar"] as? String }
                    self.crewAvatarArray = projectName
                    print(self.crewAvatarArray)

                    let subTitle = jsonData.flatMap { $0["crew_contact"] as? String }
                    self.crewContactArray = subTitle

                    let startDate = jsonData.flatMap { $0["crew_email"] as? String }
                    self.crewEmailArray = startDate
                }
            }
```

Try this code

Comment: just an advice you should always do this kind of operation in the background queue, rather than the main queue.

Comment: tq for your advice.i will change my code structure @KeranMarinov

Comment: It's not necessary at all to dispatch the parsing to the main thread since there is no UI involved. And this is not JavaScript or PHP. Variable names are supposed to be *camelCased* (e.g. `crewContactArray`)